# Can i make Pi be seen as wireless projector and stream 1080p video, but not sound to it?

Tags: video, streaming-video

I have the following setup:wireless router, NAS, Pc, Pi, Projector, Audio System.
The pi is connected to the projector via HDMI, in the back of the room, and has wireless network. The rest, Pc, Audio and Nas are at the front. What i want to do is stream video (1080) to the projector through Pi from pc, which acts as multimedia server, while keeping audio from pc to sound system. Can the Pi be seen as a Wireless projector in devices and printers in windows 8.1 or 10, and if the answer is yes, how?